Unscrew or cut old bathroom radiator
I have this old, non functional radiator (there is no water running anymore on that line).
I would like to remove it, but I would like to know: does it seem possible to remove it by unscrewing the ends, or it really looks bad enough that cutting is the best option?
I tried a little bit to untwist and it did not move.
I would prefer to uninstall it without cutting. Should I use/do anything special that would make it easier to unscrew the ends?
What is the correct rotation? I believe the right side (close to the black open/close valve) I would need use a wrench turning upwards to disconnect it, right? Because that would be counter clockwise in the radiator -> black open/close valve direction.






for a start scrubbing all the crud off the couplers would make it easier to identify the  union or ferrule connection which will be the first parts to unscrew.

There might be water in the supply pipes, even if the valves supplying this radiator are closed (preventing it from working). That may mean that you have to leave pipes sticking out of the wall with valves on them...

Considering the century of old paint combined with rust, unscrewing will be a challenge. Just cut it

Paint that looks that old is likely to contain lead. Use appropriate precautions when cutting and cleaning up the debris.
